# SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word => prettier/third-party.js

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, gulp, prettier

I'm pretty new to Node, npm and webpack. I'm trying to set up a [Craft 3 environment](https://github.com/madebyshape/craft-3) with Tailwind css.

Everything worked fine out of the box, but when i run `npm run dev` i get the following error:

```
> craftcms-tailwind@1.0.0 dev /Users//sites/***/www
> gulp dev

/Users/***/sites/***/www/node_modules/prettier/third-party.js:9871
      for await (const place of this.config.searchPlaces) {
          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/***/sites/***/www/node_modules/prettier/index.js:16551:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! craftcms-tailwind@1.0.0 dev: `gulp dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the craftcms-tailwind@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/***/.npm/_logs/2020-08-28T14_23_16_034Z-debug.log
```

Why is this hapening and how can i make sure i can fix this in the furure?

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: I updated/added/removed some Craft plugins. But did not write or touched any kind of css/js yet.

Comment: are you importing the Craft 3 package into your code?

Comment: What's your version of node ?

Comment: @KiJéy i'm running node at v8.11.3

Comment: @Ramon node 8 doesn't support this syntax (`for await... of`) you need Node 10.0.0 or later : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: @KiJéy This was the problem, thanks. Works fine now!

Comment: @Ramon then please check my answer as valid so that people can find this as a resolved issue :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

This syntax :

```js
for await (const place of this.config.searchPlaces) {
  // ...
}
```

is available in NodeJS starting version 10.0.0

Answer (score 6):

1. I faced same issue first I tried with upgrading ***node v8*** --> ***node v10*** works fine.
2. If you do not want to upgrade your node version you can downgrade prettier version to ***prettier@1.13.7*** This fix is also working properly.

Downgrade prettier version:

```
npm i -D prettier@1.13.7
```

More info: https://dev.to/shivampawar/syntaxerror-unexpected-reserved-word-prettierthird-partyjs-3ph7

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in node v8.11.2. Upgraded node to version 12.3.1 and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but for people coming here, you can either use node v10 or downgrade prettier to v1.x.x.

If any package throws an unexpected error like this please check it's package.json on github or from node_module and look for **engines**

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=8"
},
```

make sure it matches your node, either change (upgrade) the node version if possible or use a different (older) package version. You can check which package version is suitable by changing the version from dropdown for this file.